# Elementor Archive Template not showing posts (CPT)

Tags: custom-post-type, elementor

Problem: I created an Elementor archive template to display the CPT posts on a category page. Yet, it shows no posts (CPT).

The CPT is called `item`. Here are the arguments:

```
$args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Add an Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
        'taxonomies'            => array('category', 'maker', 'material', 'condition'),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-edit',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
```

Here are the template details and conditions:

[image]

[image]

When I test my template I get:

[image]

Comment: You have to click where it says "All" and then start typing a category name and your options will come up. It's not intuitive, and should have a hover tooltip, text to the side explaining this, and the "All" should change to placeholder text of "Start typing your category here ..." Hope that helps